# How can I convert the binary data for a JPEG to the actual image using JS?

Tags: javascript

I have some binary data for a JPEG image that I want to display on my website (the image should just be all white; nothing interesting).

```
\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00`\x00`\x00\x00\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\x08\x06\x06\x07\x06\x05\x08\x07\x07\x07\t\t\x08\n\x0c\x14\r\x0c\x0b\x0b\x0c\x19\x12\x13\x0f\x14\x1d\x1a\x1f\x1e\x1d\x1a\x1c\x1c $.\' ",#\x1c\x1c(7),01444\x1f\'9=82<.342\xff\xdb\x00C\x01\t\t\t\x0c\x0b\x0c\x18\r\r\x182!\x1c!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222\xff\xc0\x00\x11\x08\x01\xa4\x01\xa4\x03\x01"\x00\x02\x11\x01\x03\x11\x01\xff\xc4\x00\x1f\x00\x00\x01\x05\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\xff\xc4\x00\xb5\x10\x00\x02\x01\x03\x03\x02\x04\x03\x05\x05\x04\x04\x00\x00\x01}\x01\x02\x03\x00\x04\x11\x05\x12!1A\x06\x13Qa\x07"q\x142\x81\x91\xa1\x08#B\xb1\xc1\x15R\xd1\xf0$3br\x82\t\n\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a%&\'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xff\xc4\x00\x1f\x01\x00\x03\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\xff\xc4\x00\xb5\x11\x00\x02\x01\x02\x04\x04\x03\x04\x07\x05\x04\x04\x00\x01\x02w\x00\x01\x02\x03\x11\x04\x05!1\x06\x12AQ\x07aq\x13"2\x81\x08\x14B\x91\xa1\xb1\xc1\t#3R\xf0\x15br\xd1\n\x16$4\xe1%\xf1\x17\x18\x19\x1a&\'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xff\xda\x00\x0c\x03\x01\x00\x02\x11\x03\x11\x00?\x00\xf7\xfa(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\n(\xa2\x80\x10\x1c\x80h\xa2\x8a\x00(\xa2\x8a\x00(\xa2\x8a\x00(\xa2\x8a\x00(\xa2\x8a\x00(\xa2\x8a\x00(\xa2\x8a\x00(\xa2\x8a\x00(\xa2\x8a\x00(\xa2\x8a\x00(\xa2\x8a\x00(\xa2\x8a\x00(\xa2\x8a\x00(\xa2\x8a\x00(\xa2\x8a\x00(\xa2\x8a\x00(\xa2\x8a\x00(\xa2\x8a\x00(\xa2\x8a\x00(\xa2\x8a\x00(\xa2\x8a\x00(\xa2\x8a\x00(\xa2\x8a\x00(\xa2\x8a\x00(\xa2\x8a\x00(\xa2\x8a\x00(\xa2\x8a\x00\xff\xd9'
```

However, when I try to convert it into a base64 string and into an image using this code snippet

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + btoa('(data goes here)');
    document.body.appendChild(img);
```

it doesn't generate a valid image - just the missing image icon.

I've also tried creating an image element in the HTML file itself and then modifying its `src` using JS, but that also didn't work.

Is there anything wrong with the data itself, or can I do something to generate the image using JS?

(For extra context, I got the binary data for this image by [getting a user's profile picture using the Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0).)

Comment: When you write `\x00`, for example, does that mean you have the character sequence `\x00` or an actual NUL character?

Comment: @FZs I don't know - the data was from an API.